# No route matches [POST] "/" Stripe Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe into my rails app. Everything works well until I submit the form in which it looks like this when I do so:

[image: submission]

Once I submit the form I am getting the following error:

[image: error]

I cannot figure out why it is doing this. When I check my stripe test dashboard nothing is there.

Here are some of the files:

donation.html.erb

```
 <%= form_tag charges_path do %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <% if flash[:error].present? %>
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <article>
      <%= label_tag(:amount, 'Donation Amount:',class: 'donationHead') %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:amount,"", class: 'form-control') %>
    </article>
    <article>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:stripeToken) %>
    </article>
    <button id='donateButton' class="btn btn-primary">Donate</button>
<% end %>

   <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<script>

var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>',
  locale: 'auto',
  name: 'Place4Grace',
  image: '<%= asset_url "creative/small_logo.jpg" %>',
  description: 'Thank you for your Donation!',
  token: function(token) {
    $('input#stripeToken').val(token.id);
    $('form').submit();
  }
});

$('#donateButton').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#error_explanation').html('');

  var amount = $('input#amount').val();
  amount = amount.replace(/\$/g, '').replace(/\,/g, '')

  amount = parseFloat(amount);

  if (isNaN(amount)) {
    $('#error_explanation').html('<p>Please enter a valid amount in USD ($).</p>');
  }
  else if (amount < 5.00) {
    $('#error_explanation').html('<p>Donation amount must be at least $5.</p>');
  }
  else {
    amount = amount * 100; // Needs to be an integer!
    handler.open({
      amount: Math.round(amount)
    })
  }
});

$(window).on('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});

</script>
```

Here is my stripe.rb

```
    Rails.configuration.stripe = {
      :publishable_key => 'pk_test...',
      :secret_key      => 'sk_test...'
    }
    Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]

routes.rb

    resources :charges, only: [:new, :create]

And lastly here is my controller:

class ChargesController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
  @amount = params[:amount]

  @amount = @amount.gsub('$', '').gsub(',', '')

  begin
    @amount = Float(@amount).round(2)
  rescue
    flash[:error] = 'Charge not completed. Please enter a valid amount in USD ($).'
    redirect_to root_path
    return
  end

  @amount = (@amount * 100).to_i # Must be an integer!

  if @amount < 500
    flash[:error] = 'Charge not completed. Donation amount must be at least $5.'
    redirect_to root_path
    return
  end

  Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => @amount,
    :currency => 'usd',
    :source => params[:stripeToken],
    :description => 'Custom donation'
  )


  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my route.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'dashboard/index'

  get 'dashboard/new'

  get 'dashboard/create'

  get 'dashboard/show'

  get 'dashboard/destroy'

  get 'contacts/index'

  get 'document/download'
  get 'confirmation/confirmation'
  get 'document/download'

  root 'creatives#index'


  get 'access/menu'
  get 'access/login'
  post 'access/attempt_login'
  get 'access/logout'

  get 'sessions/index'
  get 'sessions/logout'
  get 'sessions/profile'
  get 'sessions/login'

  get 'administrators/index'
  get 'administrators/new'

  resources :users do
   member do
    get :delete
  end
end

  resources :contacts do
   member do
    get :delete
  end

end

resources :charges, only: [:new, :create]


  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

**Update 2**

[image: routes]

**Update 3**

I don't know how to fix this or if this even matters but when you create a controller using rails in the terminal it creates a view automatically. I created a charges controller but the charges form is located in the creatives view not the charges view because it is a partial see image the page is donation.html.erb.

[image: partials]

Comment: can you share your routes.rb?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal I added the routes.rb

Comment: Can you please post the output of rails routes?

Comment: @JonWahl I added the ouput of the rails routes

Comment: Sorry i may be blind, I do not see charges in the results of rails routes. It dose not look like you have any syntax errors in routes.rb and charges is present. The error is,  rails is not picking up charges from routes.rb. I would check if routes.rb is saved, restart server, ect.

Comment: You are not blind let me recheck it

Comment: @JonWahl I added the routes I had the wrong app sorry.

Comment: Please confirm that the `<form>` tag on your donation for is set to POST to the correct route, i.e. `<form action="/charges" method="POST">`. The error message you shared indicates that it's posting to / instead of the route that you want. I'd also use the Web Inspector to track where your form is sending the data, as you'll be able to instantly see the problem.